# Filter dropdown only works once - React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a dropdown filter based on the Line Code (a value from API). The filter works but only once. When trying to filter for the second time, the list goes empty. I would like to have the filter work on other options as well.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-tree-sb1cfg?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const [trains, setTrains] = useState([]);
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");

  const handleSelect = (val) => {
    setColor(val);

    let filteredColors = trains.filter((item) => {
      return item.LineCode === val;
    });

    setTrains(filteredColors);
  };

  const fetchTrains = () => {
    let api =
      "https://api.wmata.com/TrainPositions/TrainPositions?contentType=json&api_key=e13626d03d8e4c03ac07f95541b3091b";

    fetch(api)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setTrains(data.TrainPositions))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error fetching and parsing data", error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTrains();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Trains</h1>
      <LineColor trains={trains} changeOption={handleSelect} />
      <div className="card-container">
        {trains.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={index}>
              <p>Line Code:{item.LineCode}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function LineColor(props) {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");

  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    setColor(e.target.value);
    props.changeOption(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select value={color} onChange={handleSelect}>
        <option value="RD">RD</option>
        <option value="BL">BL</option>
        <option value="YL">YL</option>
        <option value="OR">OR</option>
        <option value="GR">GR</option>
        <option value="SV">SV</option>
        <option value="null">NULL</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you filter first time the original list got modified. and second time you are filtering the data which is already filtered with first value.

Comment: you need to create one another state to keep original trains values and filter from this array every time. and dont modify it

Comment: @jsN00b the thing is I plan to scale this for multiple filters on the `trains` array, that's why I can't do it on demand.

Comment: @sojin, your solution makes the most sense. I'm a beginner and still learning. I was wondering if you could show an example of that.

Comment: I may be wrong; however, I do feel that it can be done 'on demand' even if you need to do for different criteria. Simply add a `filter` object to the state. And, when color or line or any other criteria changes, update the filter object. Then, use the same to filter the `trains`. Here is [my attempt](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-chihiro-4ik1zq). The `LineColor` now has no state - it is a pure-component FWIW. Also, using `"null"` as a value caused a lot of pain in understanding - so I've switched to `"empty"`.

Comment: Please consider using a higher-order-component / wrapper and each of your filters (like colors, station, circuit-id, train-id, train-number) can be rendered using the same component. Also, please consider populating the dropdown dynamically.

Comment: @jsN00b hmm very interesting. I really like your approach. Thank you!

Comment: Please use the latest version from the sandbox. It's updated vis-a-vis [https://codesandbox.io/s/ffmhy9](https://codesandbox.io/s/ffmhy9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presented below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective (as noted by OP, and taking into consideration the need to scale this to include further columns for filtering).

Here is the main component:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";

export default function App() {
  const [trains, setTrains] = useState([]);
  const [ddOptions, setDdOptions] = useState({
    LineCode: [],
    DestinationStationCode: [],
    TrainNumber: []
  });
  const filterTitles = {
    LineCode: "Color",
    DestinationStationCode: "Destination Station",
    TrainNumber: "Train Number"
  };
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    LineCode: "",
    DestinationStationCode: "",
    TrainNumber: ""
  });

  const fetchTrains = () => {
    let api =
      "https://api.wmata.com/TrainPositions/TrainPositions?contentType=json&api_key=USE_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE";

    fetch(api)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setTrains(data.TrainPositions))
    .catch((error) => {console.log("Error fetching and parsing data", error);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTrains();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log("trains: ", trains);
    setDdOptions((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      LineCode: [
        ...new Set(trains.map(({ LineCode }) => LineCode || "empty"))
      ].concat(["all"]),
      DestinationStationCode: [
        ...new Set(
          trains.map(
            ({ DestinationStationCode }) => DestinationStationCode || "empty"
          )
        )
      ].concat(["all"]),
      TrainNumber: [
        ...new Set(trains.map(({ TrainNumber }) => TrainNumber || "empty"))
      ].concat(["all"])
    }));
  }, [trains]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Trains</h1>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        {Object.entries(ddOptions).map(([k, v]) => (
          <Dropdown
            key={k}
            title={filterTitles[k]}
            optionVal={filters[k]}
            handleChange={(ev) => {
              console.log("ev-tgt-val: ", ev.target.value);
              setFilters((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                [k]: ev.target.value
              }));
            }}
            optionsList={v}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="card-container">
        {trains
          ?.filter((train) =>
            Object.entries(filters).reduce(
              (fin, [k, v]) =>
                fin &&
                (!v ||
                  train[k] === v ||
                  (v === "empty" && !train[k]) ||
                  v === "all"),
              true
            )
          )
          ?.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div className="card" key={index}>
                <p>
                  Line Code: {item.LineCode} &emsp; &emsp; Destination Station
                  Code: {item.DestinationStationCode} &emsp; &emsp; Train
                  Number: {item.TrainNumber}
                </p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the `Dropdown` component (which is a controlled component) used to render the filter boxes, and options is as below:

```
import React from "react";

const Dropdown = (props) => {
  const { optionVal, handleChange, optionsList, title } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {title} &emsp;
      <select value={optionVal} onChange={handleChange}>
        {optionsList?.concat()?.map((val, idx) => (
          <option key={idx} value={val}>
            {val}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      &emsp; &emsp;
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

**Explanation**

- The problem with the OP's code was due to the `trains` state being mutated at each  application of the color `filter`
- This is being resolved by not mutating the `trains` array and instead creating a `filtered` array on-the-go when rendering
- Since OP indicated (in the comments below the question) that they plan to have similar feature for not just the `color` but for other columns as well, modified their child-component into a controlled component which is generic-enough to be able to render different types of filters

**Enhanced Feature**

- OP's code hard-coded the line-colors within the child-component
- This means if there was a new color added, then a code-change will be required
- Also, if an existing color was removed or renamed, then the results will no longer be shown for that color.
- Instead of hardcoding, used `.filter` on the `trains` array to gather a unique list of each `filter`
- Passed this list down to the child component for rendering the dropdown

**Open Tasks**

Edited/ Updated:

> - Dynamically alter available options when user selects one of the dropdown items.
> - If user selects "OR" line-color, then the Destination-station, Train-number, etc need to show only those options that have "OR" as a
>   line-color (ie, LineCode, in API results)

This is now handled in the [codesandbox version here](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-chihiro-4ik1zq). Solution was fairly simple: just apply the existing filters when populating the dropdown options for each filter.

Comment: The updated working version with the above changes is (temporarily) available on [this codesandbox-link](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-chihiro-4ik1zq).

Comment: Thank you. You really scaled down to what I was planning to do. I will go over your approach and try to grasp/implement it, and if I have any questions, I will circle back to you. Thanks again, really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey man, could you explain what you did in applyFilters function?

Comment: The `applyFilters` is basically the same as the logic to filter `trains` using `Object.entries(filters).reduce` in the above answer. Will explain in detail.

Comment: `applyFilters`: Iterate over the `trains` array. Now, for each `train` (an element in the array), apply each filter (from the `filters` array, using `.reduce`). Suppose there are 2 filters applied - say `LineCode` and `Destination...`, then apply both conditions to decide whether this particular `train` object needs to be filtered (ie, rendered or not).

Comment: The `.reduce` works like this. It takes a final result `fin` as `true` initially. Then, for each `filter` Object-`entry` (of the type `[k, v]` - key-value pair) it checks whether the  value `v` is false (`!v`), or the prop/key (ie, `k`, from `filter` that matches `train` object's prop) has a value that is either `v` (or numeric ie, `+v`) or `null` (in `train`, matching `"empty"` in `filter`).

Comment: A bit hairy, but once you understand, it all makes sense. I didn't know you could check the numeric by `+v`. I like it. Thank you. It's an excellent explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import LineColor from "./LineColor";

export default function App() {
  const [trains, setTrains] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState([]);
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");

  const handleSelect = (val) => {
    setColor(val);

    let filteredColors = total.filter((item) => {
      return item.LineCode === val;
    });
    setTrains(filteredColors);
  };

  const fetchTrains = () => {
    let api =
      "https://api.wmata.com/TrainPositions/TrainPositions?contentType=json&api_key=e13626d03d8e4c03ac07f95541b3091b";

      fetch(api)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setTotal(data.TrainPositions))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error fetching and parsing data", error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTrains();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Trains</h1>
      <LineColor trains={trains} changeOption={handleSelect} />
      <div className="card-container">
        {trains.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={index}>
              <p>Line Code:{item.LineCode}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
]);
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm getting a `429 (Too Many Requests)` error

Comment: please try to add "trains.length" instead of "trains"

Comment: the error doesn't show up which is good but when I select a value from a dropdown to filter it automatically changes to the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might actually be

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTrains();
  }, [color]);
```

`useEffect` needs to know when to run.

Comment: thanks, the list doesn't go empty, but the filter doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0):

Use effect takes a dependencies which is mention in `[]` , so if any of this `color` or `trains` changes than `useEffect` will render the page .
There can be more than a dependencies, `[trains,color]`.

Comment: thanks, but I'm getting a 429 (Too Many Requests) error when having `[trains]` as a dependency.

Comment: I found this github discussion ,https://github.com/ContentMine/getpapers/issues/157

Comment: Just see if it works

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) so that you can use the [single source of truth](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) `trains` and then compute adjustments to it (filtering, in this case).

For example, by changing your handleSelect to just set the color:

```
  const handleSelect = (val) => {
    setColor(val);
  };
```

You can then filter off of that `color` state, without losing your data in your  `trains` state.

```
  const filteredTrains = useMemo(
    () =>
      color
        ? trains.filter((item) => {
            if (color === "null") {
              return item.LineCode === null;
            }
            return item.LineCode === color;
          })
        : trains,
    [color, trains]
  );
```

Then you can map using the new `filteredTrains` value to set up your cards:

```
        {filteredTrains.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={index}>
              <p>Line Code:{item.LineCode}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Working example:

```js
const { useEffect, useMemo, useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [trains, setTrains] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTrains = () => {
      let api =
        "https://api.wmata.com/TrainPositions/TrainPositions?contentType=json&api_key=e13626d03d8e4c03ac07f95541b3091b";
      fetch(api)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setTrains(data.TrainPositions))
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error fetching and parsing data", error);
        });
    };
    fetchTrains();
  }, []);
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");

  const filteredTrains = useMemo(
    () =>
      color
        ? trains.filter((item) => {
            if (color === "null") {
              return item.LineCode === null;
            }
            return item.LineCode === color;
          })
        : trains,
    [color, trains]
  );
  const lines = useMemo(
    () => Array.from(new Set(trains.map((train) => train.LineCode))),
    [trains]
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Trains</h1>
      <select value={color} onChange={e=>setColor(e.target.value)}>
        {lines.map(line=>(<option key={line} value={line||'null'}>{line||'NULL'}</option>))}
      </select>
      <div className="card-container">
        {filteredTrains.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={index}>
              <p>Line Code:{item.LineCode}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: thanks, I tried your solution, but the filter still works once.

Comment: You need to remove setting the `trains` state everywhere besides the API return. As you can see in my working example link, it works fine.

Comment: the thing is I plan to scale this for multiple filters on the trains array, that's why I don't want it to render it on demand just for the specific Line Code. I would like to have it performed on the copy of the original trains array. So that I can apply other filters as well based in `card-container`